# Get objects from arrays and push to new array

Tags: javascript

I have a button which creates an array with an object like

```
[{field: field1, operator: operator1, value: 10}]
```

when I click on the button again it will again creates a new array like

```
[{field: field2, operator: operator2, value: 20}]
```

When I tried to push these into new array, it is becoming nested

```
[Array(1), Array(1)]
```

But I want the new array to look like

```
[{field: field1, operator: operator1, value: 10}, {field: field2, operator: operator2, value: 20}]
```

My code

```
public filterChange(state): void {
    this.filters.push( state.filters );
    console.log(this.filters);
}
```

On each click of the button 'filterChange' will call and 'state' will give the filters array generated with new filter values. Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Why do the buttons create arrays with a single element in the first place? Why not just the object?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) syntax. The spread operator will take an element from array:

```
this.filters.push( ...state.filters );
console.log(this.filters);
```

An example:

```js
let arr1 = [],
arr2 = [{
    user_id: 3, project_name: 'Project A'
}]

arr1.push(...arr2);
console.log(arr1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a spread syntax.

`public filterChange(state): void {
    this.filters.push( ...state.filters );
    console.log(this.filters);
}`